# Как с помошью MutationObserver отследить появления элемента на странице и скрыть его?

Tags: javascript

На странице в любой момент может появиться окно у которого есть `<div> id=a </div>` Как отследить появление этого div и применить к нему `display: none` ?
Заранее спасибо за любую помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если элемент создаётся и вставляется, то:

```
new MutationObserver( Mutations => {
  for (let Mutation of Mutations) {
    for (let Node of Mutation.addedNodes) if (Node instanceof HTMLElement) {
      if (Node.matches('#a')) Node.style.display = "none";
      else {
        let El = Node.querySelector('#a');
        if (El) El.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}).observe( document, { childList: true, subtree: true });
```

Если элемент уже присутствует на странице в скрытом виде и у него изменяется видимость (например на `display: block;`), то:

```
new MutationObserver( Mutations => {
  for (let Mutation of Mutations) {
    let El = Mutation.target;
    if (El.matches('#a') && El.style.display != "none") El.style.display = "none";
  }
}).observe( document, { attributeFilter: ['style'] });
```

Comment: XX-J... спасибо!!!

Comment: XX-J..., этот код скрывает только один элемент,  а если несколько одинаковых элементов появляются на странице, то тогда как их скрыть?

Comment: @User, вместо:
`let El = Node.querySelector('#a'); if (El) El.style.display = "none";`
 нужно написать:
`for (let El of Node.querySelectorAll('#a')) El.style.display = "none";`

Comment: XX-J  **спасибо!!!**