# Как с помощью MutationObserver отследить удаление класса и выполнить click по этому элементу?

Tags: javascript

На странице появляется кнопка `<button class="button ibtn ibtn-blue ibtn-big itbtn-disabled" onclick="take();">Забрать приз</button>` Она не активна. Через 5 секунд удаляется класс `itbtn-disabled` и кнопка становится активной. Как отследить удаление класса `itbtn-disabled` и произвести по кнопке click автоматически?

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/mutation-observer Я думаю подойдет отслеживание аттрибутов, при изменении можно будет проверить наличие класса

Answer (score 0):

Пробуйте

```js
const button = document.querySelector(".button.ibtn");

const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
  mutations.forEach(m => {
    if (
      m.type !== "attributes"
      || m.attributeName !== "class"
      || m.target.classList.contains('itbtn-disabled')
    ) return;

    m.target.click();
    observer.disconnect();
  });
});

observer.observe(button, {attributes: true});

setTimeout(() => button.classList.remove('itbtn-disabled'), 2000);
```

```html
<button class="button ibtn ibtn-blue ibtn-big itbtn-disabled" onclick="alert('Clicked');">Забрать приз</button>
```

В случае если элемент не меняет классы а удаляется с DOM и добавляется с другими классами можно при помощи того же `MutationObserver` слушать `childList` у контейнера

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".container");

const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
  mutations.forEach(m => {
    if (m.type !== "childList") {
      return;
    }
    
    const btn = m.target.querySelector(".button.ibtn");
    if (!btn) {
      return;
    }

    btn.click();
    observer.disconnect();
  });
});

observer.observe(container, { childList: true });

setTimeout(() => container.appendChild(document.querySelector(".button")), 2000);
```

```html
<div style="display: none;"><button class="button ibtn ibtn-blue ibtn-big itbtn-disabled" onclick="alert('Clicked');">Забрать приз</button></div>

<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Тёма Kornishon, к сожалению не работает.

Comment: сделал рабочим примером, всё работает

Comment: Есть вариант, что у вас не удаляется класс itbtn-disabled, а  удаляется элемент и отрисовывается такой же новый без класса itbtn-disabled

Comment: Тёма Kornishon, да, я вижу, спасибо, пример рабочий. Но у меня он не работает. Дело в том, что этот пример кода я вписываю в дополнение к браузеру User Javascript & CSS.  У меня уже имеется кусок моего кода вписанный в это расширение и он работает. Когда я добавляю этот код, то всё вообще перестаёт работать.  Если убрать из твоего кода `const observer =`   и  `observer.observe(button, {attributes: true});`  то мой код начинает работать, а твой само собой не работает. Может как-то можно по другому изменить твой код, но что-бы функцию он выполнял такую же?

Comment: Тёма Kornishon, мне один хороший человек привёл пример, тоже с mutationObserver ну там немного другая задача стояла, так тот пример заработал без проблем и сразу [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1540197/]   Если есть возможность буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: может быть observer уже создана? иначе почему когда убрать объявление все работает. есть какието ошибки? пробовали observer переменовать допустим в observer2?

Comment: Тёма Kornishon, да действительно у меня был уже observer и я его переименовал.  Теперь `const observer =` Не нужно убирать что-бы мойкод заработал. А вот  эту строчку все ровно приходится убирать `observer.observe(button, {attributes: true});` Задал имя кнопки `const button0707` и прописал её тут  `observer.observe(button0707, {attributes: true});` но это не помогло. А вот когда написал `observer.observe(document, {attributes: true});` мой код заработал, а твой само собой нет. Кнопки `button0707` точно нет у меня в коде.

Comment: а во второй фразе переименовали observer?

Comment: на момент прогрузки скрипта кнопки может не быть в DOM. проверьте нашлась ли. если не нашлась, скрипт лучше прогрузить позже, допустим по событию DOMContentLoaded у документа, оно как раз срабатывает когда документ догружен https://learn.javascript.ru/onload-ondomcontentloaded

Comment: Походу действительно там класс не удаляется, а отрисовывается такой же новый но без класса `itbtn-disabled`

Comment: Можно отследить появление `button ibtn ibtn-blue ibtn-big` и через 5 секунд выполнить Click по кнопке?

Comment: добавил пример для такого случая. Также желательно проверять что у появившейся кнопки нету класса ```itbtn-disabled```

Comment: Тёма Kornishon, а что это за контейнер container? Для чего он нужен?

Comment: родительский элемент, в котором появляется кнопка, у вас свой селектор.

Comment: Тёма Kornishon, Работает, но немного не так. Приходится обновлять страницу каждый раз что-бы код работал, выполнил клик. Допустим обновляю страницу, код срабатывает как надо, а через час когда кнопка опять появляется код не работает. Обновляю и код снова срабатывает.

Comment: Дело в том что я и думал что работать должно один раз. Строка observer.disconnect(); отвечает за отписку, если ее убрать то работать будет постоянно

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать не ждать 5 сек.:

```
new MutationObserver( Mutations => {
  for (let Mutation of Mutations) {
    for (let Node of Mutation.addedNodes) if (Node instanceof HTMLElement) {
      let El = Node.querySelector('.itbtn-disabled');
      if (Node.matches('.itbtn-disabled')) El = Node;
      if (El) El.onclick();  /*  или  {
        El.classList.remove('itbtn-disabled');
        El.removeAttribute('disabled');
        El.click();
      }  */
    }
  }
}).observe( document, { childList: true, subtree: true });
```